# Carrierwave fails in production: Can't convert nil into string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm using Fog and uploading to S3. Uploading works fine in development, but when in production, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError (can't convert nil into String):
  app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

(that line is where the picture gets saved). That's the end of the stack trace.

When I go into the console and do:

```
p = Picture.new(image: "~/rails_apps/my_app/current/app/assets/images/rails.png")
```

It gives me the following in production:

```
CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart: CarrierWave::FormNotMultipart
```

...but makes no protest in development. Perhaps that is a clue.

Any ideas why uploads aren't working in production?

Here's my carrierwave.rb initializer:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                                         # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']#,    # required
  }
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.fog_directory  = 'mydir'                     # required
  else
    config.fog_directory  = 'mydir-development'                     # required
  end
  config.fog_public     = true                                   # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}  # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Comment: Why don't you just look at  app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb line 29?

Comment: Hey @Mörre, thanks for checking out this question. That line reads `if @picture.save`. Cheers.

Comment: So, since there is no string in that line I guess the stack trace is a little longer...? No need to respond, I believe you can do more yourself (and more easily than us) before asking :) Even if somebody gives you the answer right away, I recommend trying to solve things like this on your own. I may be way off with this response, I don't know your circumstances or CarrierWave, so don't be insulted if this is not appropriate advice, please.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but did you check that AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY were set in your prod server ?

Comment: @pjam yep, the keys are both being read by the rails app when booted in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem, it turned out that my carrierwave and fog gem are outdated(they worked perfectly until I upgraded to Rails 4). Maybe you can give it a try.

```
gem 'carrierwave', '0.9.0'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.3.1'
```